# How to pass an argument to a user defined function for mapPartitions in Spark?

Tags: java, scala, hadoop, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

In Spark, you can use a user defined function for `mapPartitions`. Now my question is how can I pass an argument to it. For example, at the moment I have something like this, which is called using `rdd.mapPartitions(userdefinedFunc)`.

```
def userdefinedFunc(iter: Iterator[(Long, Array[SAMRecord])]) : Iterator[(Long, Long)] = 
{
  val res = scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.empty[(Long, Long)]

  // Code here

  res.iterator
}
```

However, I also want a constant as an argument to that user defined function, such that, for example it looks as follows.

```
def userdefinedFunc(iter: Iterator[(Long, Array[SAMRecord])], someConstant: Long) : 
 Iterator[(Long, Long)] = 
{
  val res = scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.empty[(Long, Long)]

  // Code here

  res.iterator
}
```

Now how do I call that function with `mapPartitions`. I get an error, if I just use `rdd.mapPartitions(userdefinedFunc(someConstant))`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use currying function like:

```
def userdefinedFunc(someConstant: Long)(iter: Iterator[(Long, Array[SAMRecord])]): Iterator[(Long, Long)]
```

Then `userdefinedFunc(someConstant)` would be a function with type `(iter: Iterator[(Long, Array[SAMRecord])]) => Iterator[(Long, Long)]` that you can pass to mapPartitions.